# How to add multiple class paths to classpathscanningcandidatecomponentprovider?

Tags: java, reflection, jar

I am using ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider to scan reflection, if classes are present in same folder it scans the required class but if they are present in different class path it considers either of the folder.

for example:

jar A -- reflection code for loading classes of my.package
jar B -- contains classes under my.package

folder1 --
jar A, jar B
cmd: -cp "./folder1/*" --- Loading jar B classes

folder1 --
jar A
folder2 --
jar B

cmd: -cp "./folder1/*; ./folder2/*" --- Loading no class